# How to REPLACE any form of the word null using decode in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT DECODE(
         add1,
         null,    '.',
         ' ',     '.',
         '{null}','.',
                  LTRIM( RTRIM( REPLACE( add1,'"','.'), ' '), ' ')
       ),
       code,
       add1
FROM   addrlist
```

I am trying to replace any null word (any case-insensitive word `null` or `nuLL` or `NulL` etc.) or blank value of add1 (varchar2) with a dot (`.`).

The above code does not completely achieve it, could you please suggest a better solution.

Update : the column add1 will contain only a single string null in any form which may have only spaces in the beginning or the end of the word null. Please find below some examples:

```
Input              | Expected Result
-------------------------------------
            'nuLL' |             '.'
'        NuLL    ' |             '.'     
            'null' |             '.'
NULL               |             '.'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "replace any blank value"? Is add1 a string? (varchar2 column in some table addrlist?)

Comment: Can you give some example with source string and desirable result please?

Comment: Please don't add examples in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Please provide examples with the input and the desired output - is the input only variations on the word `NULL` or will there be other words that you do not want changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d171c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SENTENCES ( sentence ) AS
          SELECT 'Null'                      FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'null'                      FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'NULL'                      FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '   Null' || CHR(9)         FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT NULL                        FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '{NULL}'                    FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '""'                        FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT ''''''                      FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '      ' ||CHR(13)||CHR(10) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not-Null'                  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

Use the regular expression `^\W*(NULL)?\W*$` - matching the start of the string `^` then zero-or-more non-word characters `\W*` then an optional `NULL` string `(NULL)?` then zero-or-more non-word characters `\W*` and finally the end-of-the-string `$` (using a case-insensitive match).

```
SELECT sentence,
       CASE WHEN sentence IS NULL THEN '.'
            ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE( sentence, '^\W*(NULL)?\W*$', '.', 1, 0, 'i' )
            END AS unnulled_sentence
FROM   SENTENCES
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT sentence,
       DECODE(
         sentence,
         NULL,
         '.',
         REGEXP_REPLACE( sentence, '^\W*(NULL)?\W*$', '.', 1, 0, 'i' )
       ) AS unnulled_sentence
FROM   SENTENCES
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d171c/1/1)**:

(Both queries give the same results)

```
| SENTENCE | UNNULLED_SENTENCE |
|----------|-------------------|
|     Null |                 . |
|     null |                 . |
|     NULL |                 . |
|    Null    |                 . |
|   (null) |                 . |
|   {NULL} |                 . |
|       "" |                 . |
|       '' |                 . |
|          |                 . |
| Not-Null |          Not-Null |
```

Comment: My sentence will contain only one string will will be NULL .
There are no letters before or after it, there might be blank spaces before or after the word null.
@MT0 could you please edit your answer accordingly and explain the regular expression you have used as I am not able to understand it

Comment: @user2077648 Please edit your question to include examples of your expected inputs and their corresponding outputs - as it is not clear what your intent is. Both answers here have interpreted your question to mean that there can be multiple NULLs in a sentences - if that is not your intent then please clarify your question.

Comment: @user2077648 See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDGHBHF for an explanation of the PERL-influenced operators used in regular expressions. `\W` matches a non-word character.

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace(nvl(add1, 'NULL'), '(^|\s)(NULL)(\s|$)', '\1.\3', 1, 0, 'im')
from 
  (select 'NUll sdfsdfasdf null xzxx nullable nil; null' as add1 from dual)
```

Result:

> . sdfsdfasdf . xzxx nullable nil; .

I assume that you want to replace only whole words NULL but not just combination of letters (that's why I put word "nullable" to leave it unchanged).

Comment: I want to use the decode function , I hope this makes my question more clear, @Rusty could you please help in this case

Comment: Well you can use any of NVL, NVL2, DECODE or CASE.  If you don't like NVL use DECODE(add1, null, 'NULL', add1). When you say "I want to use" what argumentation you can provide? What's wrong with NVL?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
DECLARE 
    xi VARCHAR2(100) := NULL;
        xi_decode VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
        SELECT DECODE(xi, NULL, 0, 1) INTO xi_decode FROM Dual;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(xi_decode);
END;
/
```

On the position of the '1' you could place another DECODE(). 
In my example it looks like if DECODE is NULL, in that case we replace it by 0. 
If that is not the case it will be '1'.

Here is a link that explains things very nice I think: [Link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

It is strange to have a string in a database filled with the word 'NULL' or 'Null' or whatever.

But, well, you want to replace empty strings and those containing the word 'NULL' with a dot. You can do this with DECODE, as you tried yourself. Only trim the string of blanks and convert it to lower case for easier comparision:

```
select decode( lower(trim(add1))   ,   null,'.'   ,   'null','.'   ,   add1)
from addrlist;
```

Comment: This answer is also correct and it works for me, thank you very much!!